# How to Change Type of Column in Subscription Table

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Cashier 10.7 and Stripe 7 and Laravel 5.8. I have integrated Cashier into my application and now I want to change type of 'ends_at' column. However, subscription table migration, migrate auto, and migration folder does not contain subscription migration. Then how can I solve this. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

1. First create migration

   php artisan make:migration change_ends_at_type_to_subscription_table

2)paste the below line

```
$table->type('ends_at')->change();
```

3)run command

```
php artisan migrate
```